# Root password change using usermod

Tags: linux, root, usermod

I'm trying to implement an automated root password change for our Linux boxes.   I'm generating a hash in the script since users will be able to see the contents of the script.

I found that you can pass a hash with the `usermod` utility.  However, I'm running into a variable substitution issue as seen below.

Example:

```
# usermod -p $1$0J8av/8N$LIKB2G56XJn2IXp0XzERo1 root

# grep root /etc/shadow
root:-bashJ8av/8N:15709:0:99999:7:::
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surround the password on the `usermod` command with single quotes `''` or escape the $ with '\$'

Like this

```
# usermod -p '$1$0J8av/8N$LIKB2G56XJn2IXp0XzERo1' root
```

or

```
# usermod -p \$1\$0J8av/8N\$LIKB2G56XJn2IXp0XzERo1 root
```

Comment: Thanks, the single quotes worked.  I was trying double quotes.

Comment: Double quotes, as you noticed, still allow for variable interpolation. Single quotes on the other hand, don't.